# RecyclerView Cards not visible in the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Im trying to view data from firebase using recyclerview in a fragment.But i cant see any cards in the fragment. By cards i mean the layout ive made out for the recycler view.

this is my fragment class

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        feedView=inflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.frag_home,container,false);

        myFeed = (RecyclerView) feedView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_View);
        myFeed.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        feedref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Feed");

        return feedView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions option =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<news>()
                .setQuery(feedref,news.class)
                .build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<news,newsViewHolder> adapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<news, newsViewHolder>(option) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final newsViewHolder newsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull news news) {

            feedref.child("News").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("Desc")){
                        String headline = dataSnapshot.child("Title").getValue().toString();
                        String content = dataSnapshot.child("Desc").getValue().toString();

                        newsViewHolder.title.setText(headline);
                        newsViewHolder.desc.setText(content);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });


            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public newsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
               View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.carview,parent ,false);
               newsViewHolder viewHolder = new newsViewHolder(view);
               return viewHolder;
            }
        };

        myFeed.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    public static class newsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title,desc;
        ImageView pic;


          public newsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
              desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
              pic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pic);


        }
    }
}
```

I see just the empty fragment layout.Ive already added the database to firebase.The code compiles without any error.I have no idea whats wrong.Im a newbie please help out.

Answer (score 0):

You have not returned the ViewHolder class in OnBindViewHolder

Comment: I dont get it. why do i need to return it in OnBindViewHolder. I return the ViewHolder class in newViewHolder